# Throwing status 500 internal error in jmeter post method same req ceated the complete data

Tags: jmeter, http-status-code-500

Requirement : performance testing in jmeter, one field can have multiple comma separated values.To know the breaking point ran the post api with 5 thread it was successful.Then tried with 8 then few got passed 200 ok most of the requests failed with 500 .when I checked the data in my db...data was created.
My query is that why this post requests showing 500 in jmeter although data is created in db.

Achieved this scenario: used CSV data element to pass all the requests and bash pre processor to get multiple vales in one field

Example
Col names : name email purcode
Sunil Sunil@gmail.com 564D@567C

Bash pre processor
Passed variable
Replace @ with commma

Answer (score 1):

As per [500 Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) description:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 500 Internal Server Error server error response code indicates that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. **Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request** to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

So you should inspect your application log for any suspicious entries, the reason or at least a clue regarding what went wrong should be there.

Given your test is successful for less amount of sent data most probably your application gets overloaded when you're sending more data hence cannot properly handle the request so in addition to checking the logs you might want to:

1. Check that the application and middleware (load balancer, application server, database, etc.) are properly configured for high loads
2. Check that the aforementioned systems don't lack CPU, RAM, etc. It can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) if you don't have an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) in place

Also be aware that it's possible to mark the requests having HTTP Status Code 500 as successful using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an unhandled error condition by the developer of the app.  You are sending data in a format that the system was not designed to handle.

Short answer: ask the developer why your post is incorrect.

Comment: Unhandled u meant I am sending mutiple values to a field, actually api accepting the mutiple values in one field which will be comma separated to achieve that used  shell pre processor and @ to ,

Comment: Take the conversation to the developer of the interface.  This is an unhandled exception for their code.